# Odoo 11.0 installation error on centos 6.9

Tags: centos6, odoo-10

I am getting the following error from past two days please help in resolving it:

> --> Finished Dependency Resolution
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>             Requires: python3-passlib
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>             Requires: python3-qrcode
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>             Requires: python3-pyserial
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>             Requires: python3-pyldap
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>             Requires: python3-PyPDF2
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>             Requires: python3-pydot
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>             Requires: python3-decorator
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>             Requires: python3-markupsafe
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>             Requires: python3-xlwt
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>             Requires: python3-vatnumber
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>             Requires: python3-greenlet
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>             Requires: python3-mock
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>             Requires: python3-docutils
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>             Requires: python3-requests
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>             Requires: python3-suds
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>             Requires: python3-reportlab
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>              Requires: python3-lxml
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>              Requires: python3-num2words
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>              Requires: python3-mako
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>              Requires: python3-six
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>              Requires: python3-pytz
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>              Requires: python3-ofxparse
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>              Requires: python3-stdnum
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>              Requires: python3-xlrd
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>              Requires: python3-html2text
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>              Requires: python3-babel
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>              Requires: python3-jinja2
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>              Requires: python3-pillow
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>              Requires: python3-pyparsing
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>              Requires: python3-feedparser
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>              Requires: python3-vobject
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>              Requires: python3-dateutil
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>              Requires: python3-werkzeug
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>              Requires: python3-psutil
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>              Requires: python(abi) = 3.6
>              Installed: python-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64 (@updates)
>                  python(abi) = 2.6
>              Available: python34-3.4.5-4.el6.i686 (epel)
>                  python(abi) = 3.4
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>              Requires: python3-pyusb
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>              Requires: python3-PyYAML
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>              Requires: python3-psycopg2
>   Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20180216-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>              Requires: python3-gevent
>    You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
>    You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

And other thing is when I check `psql -V` in centos its showing the version where as when I give `postgres -V` the error is command not found.

**Odoo Installation**

*I'm trying to connect server*

Starting postgresql-9.5 service:

```
[root@kcbsdev ~]# su - postgres -c "psql"
```

psql (9.5.11)

Type "help" for help.

Comment: What are you doing to get the errors? Are you following an installation guide? Where are you at in the overall process?